# have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near at line 1

Tags: php, html, mysqlimport

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {
if (isset($_POST['books'])) {
$b1 = implode(',' , $_POST['books']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES ('$b1)";
 if($conn->query($sql)=== TRUE){

   echo "your data is saved";
}else{
    echo"try again".$conn->error;
}



$conn->close();?>


<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <h3>Select your Books</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="book1">Book 1

    <input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="book2">Book 2

    <input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="book3">Book 3
    <input type="submit" name="btn">

</form>
```

i'm beginner in PHP i'm trying  to insert data in db using check boxes  but an error appear every time
" have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''book1,book2,book3)' at line 1"

Comment: Missing a single quote. 

_$sql = "INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES ('$b1')";_

Comment: That should be the answer not a comment @pr1nc3 :-)

Comment: i think i got it  $sql = "INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES ('$b1)";  a " ' " was ('$b1') missing

Comment: thanks  Bananaapple

Comment: Ok @Bananaapple posted it as an answer. Thanks for mentioning :)

Comment: Should just be closed as a simple typo bug really...

Comment: @AtifRaja -note that you are passing unsanitised user input (`$_POST`) directly into your query, leaving you open to SQL injection attacks. Have a look here for how to prevent this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES ('$b1)";
-------------------------------------------------^
             missing single quote around the value
```

to:-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES ('$b1')";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES ('$b1')";
```

You were missing a single quote but still it's a bad practice for insert queries as you are wide open to sql injection. Will update my answer shortly about optimizing your query to make it more secure to use.

**Prepared statement Update**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $b1);

if ($stmt->execute()) { 
 echo "your data is saved";
}else{
    echo"try again".$conn->error;
}
```

This query is using mysqli prepared statement securing you from sql injection. As you said you are really new in php so it's better to learn the correct ways from the start. In development there are many ways to do things but not all of them are right and some leave you open to threats. [Here is a great answer from stackoverflow to have a look as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: can we insert line break in  $b1 = implode('<br>' , $_POST['books']); like this?

Comment: yes , `implode("\n",$_POST['books']);` but also yours should work

Comment: If it works then please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES ($b1)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $b1);
$stmt->execute();
 if($conn->query($stmt)=== TRUE){      Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in "how to solve this one?"

Comment: Updated my answer and replaced your previous if statement. If it still doesn't work check if you set your table name, field name correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
if (isset($_POST['btn'])) {

$b1 = implode(',' , $_POST['books']);


$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO books(book_name) VALUES ('$b1')");
 if($sql=== TRUE){

   echo "your data is saved";
}else{
    echo"try again".$conn->error;
}


}
$conn->close();
?>


<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <h3>Select your Books</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="book1">Book 1

    <input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="book2">Book 2

    <input type="checkbox" name="books[]" value="book3">Book 3
    <input type="submit" name="btn">

</form>
```